# How did the originally honorific forms of address 君、お前、貴様 become informal or even insulting?

Tags: etymology

君 means ruler,
お前 honourable one towards me,
貴様 worthy appearance.

How did these originally honorific terms of address become informal or even insulting?

Comment: Is [君]{きみ} (assuming that's what we are talking about rather than ~君 [the 呼び])always marked as informal or insulting? My sense is no.

Comment: You might compare with "governor" as used by cabbies and other epithets used ironically ?

Answer (score 9):

Something similar happened in English, where "you", a formerly polite form which contrasted with "thou", is now the common second person pronoun with no inherent politeness.

It's a kind of semantic change called pejoration. In a society which values politeness, people will use a word B which sounds nicer/more polite than the usual word A. Once everybody uses B, B will become the norm, and people will start using a new word C to sound polite. Once C is being used as the polite word, using A will have become rude.

Comment: Maybe it was just me so feel free to revert, but the tenses were bothering in the last part of your second paragraph. +1 for an interesting and instructive explanation.